# Is it possible to read/access SMS through an iOS application (> ios7)

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

In a non jail broken iphone is it possible to access/read sms from an iphone application.

I have read that in case of an Android phone this thing is possible, as i need to develop an ios app which can automatically read an OTP sent through an sms to a user.

Since iOS application is sandboxed, i just want to confirm the possibility to do it legally.

Comment: What's an OTP? Why is it being sent by SMS?

Comment: On Time Password it is @Tommy.

Answer (score 0):

No.... it's not possible in `iOS` because it's privacy issue.

Comment: How the Walnut like expenses app reads the sms data ?